# How to solve Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: java, jsp

How can I avoid my application to throw this exceptions?? My jsp's are becoming slow because of it.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:462)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorResponseWrapper.sendError(MonitorResponseWrapper.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:296)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.jsp.relatorio_002dgarantias_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f2(relatorio_002dgarantias_jsp.java:485)
    at org.apache.jsp.relatorio_002dgarantias_jsp._jspService(relatorio_002dgarantias_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you put more information of the app you working? Did you have Spring Security there? Check logs above this exception. There should be more info about causing this message.

Comment: I've just posted the complete error

Comment: Hm, very strange. I had similar error when I used Spring Security and I had wrong certificate or I was unauthorised and response could not send back error.